# Converting responsive web app to Mobile app?

Tags: java, android, mobile, responsive-design, mobile-application

I have my responsive web application in place which works across all browsers. Now i am planning to work convert it into 
mobile application. Did some googling and can think of below ways to come up with mobile app

**Approach 1 :-**
Can be done  with the help of [WebView](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_webview_layout.htm) (which actually will work as thin wrapper)

**Approach 2 :-**

**Native App:-** . Develop Native app. Now, If I need to develop the native , Can i use existing backend java code for Android/IOS/Windows platform or do i need to make modifications in that ?
If yes will these modification vary per platform i.e. Android/IOS?
For User interface, i believe i need to develop altogether separate views. Is that correct ? If yes will there be separate views for android and IOS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your backend java code is sitting on a server behind some sort of API (REST etc.) then it can be used by both applications.

If you are developing natively for both platforms then you will need separate views. There are however solutions for developing for both platforms using a single codebase see: [Xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com/) [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/)

Comment: `If your backend java code is sitting on a server behind some sort of API (REST etc.) then it can be used by both applications` If that's the case, where does android sdk fits ?

Comment: Native android app would be like your HTML, Javascript frontend.

Comment: The pattern that I was referring to was that the android application (where the android sdk lives) would be making requests to the server hosting your backend. If you want the backend to live on the device then you will run into complications on the iOS side.